# Creating HBase table for files in HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to load all files data in a HDFS directory into HBase existed table.Can you please share me how to load all files data and incremental data into HBase table.
I created HBase table as

```
hbase>create 'sample','cf'
```

I have to copy

```
hdfs://ip:port/user/test
```

into sample hbase table.please suggest me any solution.

Comment: tried any of these? - http://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2015/09/09/some-ways-load-data-from-hdfs-to-hbase/

Comment: I tried ImportTSV but it's taking data from one file only,but i am looking for entire directory.

Comment: in ImportTSV, if you try providing `/user/hadoop/` directory path only instead of full file path, it should process all files with in that dir

Comment: Thank you,that is working.can you tell me how to specify a HBASE_ROW_KEY for two columns in that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1:**(possible)
[ImportTSV](http://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2015/09/09/some-ways-load-data-from-hdfs-to-hbase/), if you try providing `/user/hadoop/` directory path only instead of full file path, it should process all files with in that dir.

**Answer 2:**(seems not possible)

> The special column name [HBASE_ROW_KEY](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv) is used to designate that this
>   column should be used as the row key for each imported record. You
>   must specify exactly one column to be the row key, and you must
>   specify a column name for every column that exists in the input data.